# Where are types used in Entity Framework T4 templates defined?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4

In the `.tt` files created by Entity Framework for my entities and `DbContext` generation, I see classes like `TypeMapper` and `Accessibility` used. Where are these types defined and are they documented anywhere? I want to customize my t4 templates, but it's difficult not knowing what any of these classes do or how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework T4 template has *include* directive at the top of the file. For C# it will look like:

```
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
```

This file can be found in Visual Studio IDE extensions folder. E.g. by default for Visual Studio 2017 it will be:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity
>   Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\

This file contains helper classes which are used for entities generation. E.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Responsible for encapsulating the retrieval and translation of the CodeGeneration
/// annotations in the EntityFramework Metadata to form that is useful in code generation.
/// </summary>
public static class Accessibility
```

Second class `TypeMapper` is defined in the context generation template itself.

Comment: Thank you. For Visual Studio 2013, it is located at 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes`